# Unexpected output using theme customizer

Tags: theme-customizer

I am setting up a textarea input for theme customizer. It seems to be working well apart from it outputting a line of text above the textarea label which I cannot find where it comes from and why.

[image: Theme customizer settings]

In this screenshot, above the label *Säätiön toiminta*, is the text `data-customize-setting-link='textarea_setting'` This is somehow being automatically generated.

**Function**

```
function mytheme_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {
    require_once(TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/customizer_classes/wp_customizer_textarea.php');

    $wp_customize->add_setting('textarea_setting', array(
                               'default' => 'default text',
                               'transport' => 'refresh'
                               ));

    $wp_customize->add_section( 'Mytheme_content' , array(
        'title'      => __( 'Site content', 'Mytheme' ),
        'priority'   => 30,
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_control(new Mytheme_Textarea_Control($wp_customize, 'textarea_setting', array(
        'label' => 'Säätiön toiminta',
        'section' => 'Mytheme_content',
        'settings' => 'textarea_setting'
    )));
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'mytheme_customize_register' );
```

**wp_customizer_textarea.php**

```
class Mytheme_Textarea_Control extends WP_Customize_Control {
    public $type = 'textarea';
    public function render_content() {
        echo '<label>
        <span class="customize-control-title">' . esc_html( $this->label ) . '</span>
        <textarea rows="5" style="width:100%;" ' . $this->link() . '>' . esc_textarea( $this->value() ) . '</textarea>
    </label>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One ootion is that the HTML that you generate is broken and that is the reason something that should have been an html attribute is displayed.

Another is that $this->link() echos instead for returning a value.

Comment: Yes you are right, $this -> link() does echo. Thanks